# How AWS cloudfront knows when the origin is updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured cloudfront distribution with OAI and S3 as origin. So the request from user goes from `User -> Edge Location -> CloudFront-> S3`. Based on the documentation CloudFront can also cache frequently accessed objects.
Question:
1>When object is updated in S3 how does cloudfront know that the object is changed at origin? Is there any trigger from S3-> CloudFront -> Edge?
2>If there is no trigger, then how do we trigger cloudfront redistribution of objects from S3? ( this is typically after code deployment to s3)

Answer (score 0):

> When object is updated in S3 how does cloudfront know that the object is changed at origin? Is there any trigger from S3-> CloudFront -> Edge?

It does not "know" that immediately, until objects in cache expire. You have to [refresh catch manually](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/) or build an automation for that yourself, to for cache invalidation.

> If there is no trigger, then how do we trigger cloudfront redistribution of objects from S3? ( this is typically after code deployment to s3)

You have to [invalidate](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/) the cache yourself, as explained earlier.